# Jenkins is not getting start on windows 10

Tags: java, jenkins

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected 1 instance of hudson.PluginManager$PluginUpdateMonitor but got 0
    at hudson.ExtensionList.lookupSingleton(ExtensionList.java:451)
    at hudson.PluginManager$PluginUpdateMonitor.getInstance(PluginManager.java:2188)
    at hudson.maven.PluginImpl.init(PluginImpl.java:58)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:104)
Caused: java.lang.Error
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:110)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:175)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1133)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:50)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1166)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:966)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:233)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:250)
```

Recently install Jenkins by downloading its war file(jenkins.war), and installation I downloaded some maven plugins and then I tried to restart it again but did not find any way to restart it.
so I just open the cmd and hit the command java -jar jenkins.war. After that Jenkins stops(cmd showing the message: jenkins.model.Jenkins#cleanUp: Jenkins stopped).

Now how can I start it again, when I am hitting the localhost:8080/jenkins, it is showing the above error.

Comment: looks like a plugin is not starting, what does you jenkins log file say?  https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/issues/479

Comment: it is showing the above error: "Expected 1 instance of hudson.PluginManager$PluginUpdateMonitor but got 0"

Comment: Why don't you use the regular setup program for Windows?

Comment: I used the proper setup program, but after downloading the needed plugins, there was no option to restart the Jenkins.